# How to sum up values in the list

Tags: apex, tasks

The first system debug prints

```
Test:{a0IW00000039sLOMAY=(2.0), a0IW0000003IoM7MAK=(5.0), a0IW0000003It2GMAS=(3.0, 8.0)}.
```

The second system debug prints `18` which is the sum, but what I am trying to achieve is have it sum on a per record basis.  What I am looking for is the sum on a record basis and not the total of ALL records. For example this should be the output:

```
Test:{a0IW00000039sLOMAY=(2.0), a0IW0000003IoM7MAK=(5.0), a0IW0000003It2GMAS=(11.0)}
```

---

```
for(Task t : LogTasks){
    if(t.Test__c == 'Test1')
    {
        HoursSpent = t.Hours_Spent__c;
        impProjectIds.add(t.WhatId);
        List<Decimal> temp = HoursSpent.get(t.WhatId);
        if(temp == null){
            HoursSpent.put(t.WhatId, new List<Decimal>{currentHoursSpent});
        }
        else{
            temp.add(currentHoursSpent);
        }
        totalHours += currentHoursSpent;

        System.debug(HoursSpent);
        System.debug(totalHours);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Map` with a `Decimal`, not a `Map` with a `List`.

```
Map<Id,Decimal> hoursSpentMap = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
```

in the loop:

```
 HoursSpent hoursSpent = t.Hours_Spent__c;
 Decimal hoursTotal = HoursSpent.get(t.WhatId) == null ? 0 :  HoursSpent.get(t.WhatId);
 if (hoursSpent != null){
    HoursSpent.put(t.WhatId, hoursTotal + hoursSpent);
 }
```

Comment: You had first answer, so you can have it. Mine's basically a duplicate.

Comment: Oh I feel bad now... your answer had some nice stuff in it I reckon.

Comment: Nothing Earth-shattering, really, it was just more code/more complete example. And yours isn't bad, you know.